Is there a possibility to get Font Name and Size from a Style without having to apply it to a paragraph in Apache POI (java)?
I can get the style (Heading1 for example) with doc.getStyles().getStyle("Heading1") [where doc is a XWPFDocument].
But I don't know how to get informations like font name, font size...from the style.
I can create a paragraph, apply the style to it and get the information from that paragraph...
But there must be a better way to retrieve these informations without having to modify the document?
I use this to give my students the possibility to check if their exercises about styles are correct. From experience, at first, students tend to modify the paragraph formatting instead of modifying the style itself. So, if I only check those informations from the paragraph [I can do that with paragraph.getRuns().get(...).getFontName() as explained in other posts] , the formatting will be correct even if the student didn't solve the exercise correctly.
